# JS change src on all images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site, where I need to get all the images for eu.site.com, but the images are on us.site.com.

I would like to replace source on all of the images. Current function, that does not work:

```
$('img').each(function () {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', src.replace(/_eu(\.[^.]+)?$/, '_us$1');
});
```

Comment: `src.replace('_eu', '_us')` do not work?

Comment: Define "does not work"; is it modifying the URLs correctly, but not displaying them?  Are the generated URLs wrong?  Are the src attributes unchanged?  Something else?

Comment: I think you are overengineering, just replace one string with the other one.. no special characters are needed

Comment: Sounds like this is a job for the server, not for the client. Why in first place have you wrong image path???

Comment: I found my mistake, in having added the "_"'s...

Comment: BTW, be aware, using this kind of workaround, client side, will still make the browser trying to catch wrong images before you set relevant path, that's really not a good idea

Comment: I know, the best thing would be to change to relative or a PHP solution. But I'm working on a stupid dual-site WP page on a single table setup. I don't want to modify the core files too much because of stability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
$('img').each(function () {
    this.src = this.src.replace("eu.site.com", "us.site.com"); 
});
```